# "Excluding" a code file in resources from IntelliJ

Tags: intellij-idea

I have a groovy file in my test resources folder (e.g. `abc.groovy`)

Because I use it like a resource.

Everything works fine except it is red squiggly underlined since IntelliJ thinks it is a code file (actually I use it more like an include file for a scripting engine, which is why I have it in a resources folder)

How can I stop IntelliJ from thinking it is runnable code? I don't want to exclude it from the project completely since it I want it in Version control and available for searching.

It is red underlined because it contains some non-groovy syntax as well (which my program recognizes, but IntelliJ does not)

It will show up in "Problems" sidebar (but not in Problems at the bottom of the IDE, and doesn't prevent code from running)

Comment: Did you try [excluding it from compilation](http://i.imgur.com/LBQSjtz.png) and configuring the [per-file highlighting level](http://i.imgur.com/GQQtvnV.png)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can mark that file as plain text (there's an action for that if you right-click on the file in Project View).